# controller loding error in codignater?

Tags: php

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View_job extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->load->model('Userdb', '', TRUE);
      $this->load->model('Locationdb');
      $this->load->model('All_functiondb');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');        
  }
}
```

///

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Indexpg::$session
>
> Filename: php_include/authenticate.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-job-site-master\hindusthanjobs\application_candidate_6423\php_include\authenticate.php
>   on line 3

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: my page has error like Message: Undefined property: Indexpg::$session

Answer (score 0):

define session after tis line

```
   <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH'))  exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

first thing is that check is session library is loded in controller.

```
  public function __construct()
       {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
       }
```